# No visible interface for UIImagePickerController declares the selector isSourceTypeAvailable

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use an `UIImagePickerController` to capture some photos in my app. I created a `UIImagePickerController` object and it's telling me

```
"isSourceTypeAvailable:" is not a method.
```

Is there something I need to import or something along those lines? I've added `MobileCoreServices` to my framework library (not sure why) and tried importing " in my header file. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isSourceTypeAvailable:` method is a class method, not an instance method. Call it like this:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
}
```

instead of calling the method on your image picker instance.

If you look at the reference docs for `isSourceTypeAvailable:` you can see it is a class method because it has a `+` instead of `-`.